# WCF - how to expose strongly typed objects to clients from a base type (without client casting?)

Tags: c#, wcf, inheritance, casting

I have a WCF service that needs to return different types of Quotes 
(ie Quote1, Quote2, Quote3) -- all inherit from Quote

My plan is to expose a single method

```
Quote GetQuote(Message message);
```

However then I am forcing the client to do something like this

if (quote is Quote1)
elseif (quote is Quote2)  etc

Without having a different method for each quote type is there a good way to distinguish Quotes without having the client cast to each type?

Anyone have any suggestions on a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: are these Quote objects in libraries that are shared between client and server or are they generated from the service description?  ie do they have behaviour or are the just DTOs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `DataContracts` then you can decorate them with the [`KnownTypeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx).

Comment: already doing this like  
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Quote))]
        [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Quote1))]
        [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Quote2))]
        [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Quote3))]
        [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Quote4))]

however the client still has to cast to the type

Comment: @Chris - I typically write the wsdl/schema first so I am not sure how the autogenerated schema looks - but if I remember correctly the DataContractSerializer passes an indicator of which type was serialized which the consumer can check to know which type to Deserialize into. This is similar to strategies used  in ORM tools when mapping relational constructs to OO inheritance schemes.

Answer (score 2):

Either expose different method for each `Quote` type or do the cast on the client - that is the whole point of exposing the base type. There is no way to avoid casting if you expose the base type and you need to work with derived types on the client.

You can also define single logic of your `Quote` type which will serve all your needs (including methods working with `Quote` data) - derived types will override some functionality. Then you can share assembly with `Quote` definitions between the server and the client application and use polymorphism.